# Run several asynchronous functions in parallel

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, control-flow

I have one object which contains two different methods

```
var samp {
 m1: func1,
 m2: func2
}
```

Depending on the number of keys I want to call all the three function parallely
Now Im using the following code which runs serially.

```
switch (sampType) {
            case "m1":
            {
                return new func1();
                break;
            }
            case "m2":
            {
                return new func2();
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
            }
        }
```

How can I execute all the methods parallely in node.js? Any help on this will be really helpful

Comment: None of your examples have any asynchronous logic, can you expand what you are looking for a bit? You cannot run 3 synchronous tasks in parallel because Node is single-threaded.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Ya rite node is single threaded.So cant we execute functions parallely?

Comment: my requirement is to run all the functions parallely without waiting for one function to complete.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [async.parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel). You would essentially write:

```
async.parallel( [

    function ( callback ) {
        // Code
    },

    function ( callback ) {
        // Code
    }

], function ( error, results ) {
    // Both done
} );
```

Comment: Instead of switch case, async.parallel has to be used? func1() involves I/O opeartion so will async work properly?

Comment: Yes. You would just call `callback( error )` in your I/O callback. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Step.js](https://github.com/creationix/step/) or [bacon.js](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email) or [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

With bacon.js, you can do things like:

```
var result  = Bacon.fromNodeCallback(func1, parameters).toProperty();
var onemore = Bacon.fromNodeCallback(func2, parameters).toProperty();
```

Those two functions are going to be executed on parallel. And then you can have a function to use those two vars like this:

```
var combined = Bacon.combineAsArray(result, onemore);
combined.onValue(function (an_array) {
   // do stuff with an_array, which contains result and onemore
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another elegant way to do this - using "wiring":

```
var l = new Wire();

func1(l.branch('post'));
func2(l.branch('comments'));

l.success(function(results) { ... });
// result will be object with results: { post: ..., comments: ...}
```

https://github.com/garmoshka-mo/mo-wire